# Undocumented DEVICE_INFO cookie being dropped for iframe-embedded videos

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

After embedding any YouTube video via `iframe`, the devtools Application tab shows a `DEVICE_INFO` cookie being dropped, but I could not find any documentation on what that cookie is being used for.

I've tried searching online for this specific cookie, but nothing was found on Google/YouTube documentation nor on any of the cookie Wikis.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. [Here](https://heavensdreammessages.com/cookie-policy/) I have found description that seems to be true:

> Used to track user’s interaction with embedded content. 180 days.